# Prove the following statement involving limits of sequences

Tags: limits

I am struggling to prove the following statement: suppose $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=a$ and $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n=b$.  If $a_n\lt b_n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $a\lt b$.

So far, I have written the definitions of $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=a$ and $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n=b$.  I think that the proof is fairly straightforward, but am not yet sure how to construct it. 
Could you please suggest a hint?

Comment: The statement is not true as you've written it. You can only conclude that $a\leq b$.

Comment: That's a helpful comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is not true generally. For a counter-example you can take $a_n=-\frac1n$ and $b_n=0$